# Mathematica thinks that an initial condition is a boundary condition

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method, warning-messages

I would like to solve the following reaction-diffusion problem in Mathematica using NDSolve:

```
DiffConst = 150;
kon = 0.14/60;
koff = 0.18/60;
leftBoundary = 0.;
rightBoundary = 10.;
eqs = {D[L[x, t], t] == DiffConst*D[L[x, t], {x, 2}] + koff*LR[x, t] - 
    kon*L[x, t]*R[x, t] + NeumannValue[0, x == leftBoundary] + 
    NeumannValue[0, x == rightBoundary],
  D[LR[x, t], t] == -koff*LR[x, t] + kon*L[x, t]*R[x, t] + NeumannValue[0, x == leftBoundary] + 
    NeumannValue[0, x == rightBoundary],
  D[R[x, t], t] == koff*LR[x, t] - kon*L[x, t]*R[x, t] + NeumannValue[0, x == leftBoundary] + 
    NeumannValue[0, x == rightBoundary],
  L[x, 0] == 10,
  R[0, 0] == 10,
  LR[x, 0] == 0}
NDSolve[eqs, {L, R, LR}, {t, 0, 100}, {x, 0, 10}]
```

The idea is to apply no-flux boundary conditions (with the NeumannValue functions) and apply the initial conditions in the last three lines (LR is zero all over, L is 10 everywhere, and R is 10 at x=0).
I get the "`NDSolve::bcedge`: Boundary condition R[0,0]==10 is not specified on a single edge of the boundary of the computational domain" error message. R[0,0] is supposed to be an initial condition, but Mathematica believes it is a boundary condition. What's the problem?
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Perhaps it should be  `R[0, t] == 10` ?

Comment: Or rather R[x,0] == 10, since it's an initial condition. Setting R[0,0]=10 clashes with your Neumann conditions for the left boundary at x=0, since they are independent of t. You might also consider using the predicate in the Neumann condition to excise the point {0,0} to avoid any further conflict using an inequality instead of the default True everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to solve it. Note that there is no need for the NeumannValue, as the 0 NeumannValue is the default. I have changed the initial condition on `R` and gave a method option to use the finite element method:

```
DiffConst = 150;
kon = 0.14/60;
koff = 0.18/60;
leftBoundary = 0.;
rightBoundary = 10.;
eqs = {D[L[x, t], t] == 
    DiffConst*D[L[x, t], {x, 2}] + koff*LR[x, t] - 
     kon*L[x, t]*R[x, t](*+NeumannValue[0,x==leftBoundary]+
   NeumannValue[0,x==rightBoundary]*), 
   D[LR[x, t], t] == -koff*LR[x, t] + 
     kon*L[x, t]*R[x, t](*+NeumannValue[0,x==leftBoundary]+
   NeumannValue[0,x==rightBoundary]*), 
   D[R[x, t], t] == 
    koff*LR[x, t] - kon*L[x, t]*R[x, t](*+NeumannValue[0,x==
   leftBoundary]+NeumannValue[0,x==rightBoundary]*),
   L[x, 0] == 10, R[x, 0] == 10, LR[x, 0] == 0};
res = NDSolveValue[eqs, {L, R, LR}, {t, 0, 100}, {x, 0, 10}, 
  Method -> {"PDEDiscretization" -> {"MethodOfLines", 
      "SpatialDiscretization" -> "FiniteElement"}}]
```

Comment: Thanks. This is syntactically correct, but not what I wanted to achieve. I wanted R to be 0 everywhere at t=0, except at a certain location.
This is the code I replaced R[x,0]==10 with:
R[x, 0] == If[x == 0, 10, 0]
or
R[x, 0] == If[ 0 <= x <= 0.1, 10, 0]